# array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Tags: php, arrays

Whats wrong in the array_values() function.

I tried assigning the $updated_f to array().

I get Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

```
$this_params = array_merge_recursive($params, array('f' => array($filter['prefix'] => array($item['id'])))); 

if (isset($this_params['f'])) {
    $updated_f = array(); 
   //Updated code
    if(isset($this_params['f']) && is_array($this_params['f']) && count($this_params['f']) >0)
    {
      foreach($this_params['f'] as $f_key => $assoc_array) {
         $updated_f[$f_key] = array_values($assoc_array);   //Warning here
       } 
    }
    $this_params['f'] = $updated_f;
  }
```

Comment: Pretty obvious isn't it?  On at least one of the loops, $assoc_array is not an array, it is null.  Print out `$this_params['f']` and you'll see it...

Comment: check `var_dump($this_params['f']);` OR `echo "<pre/>";print_r($this_params['f']);`  and check is it printing an array or not? to prevent yourself from error you need to add:-  `if (isset($this_params['f']) && is_array($this_params['f']) && count($this_params['f']) >0) {`

Comment: Yes i printed out : echo '<pre>';print_r($this_params['f']); and i get :      Array ( [r_103] => Array ( [0] => 62 ) )

Comment: Please print out `$assoc_array`

Comment: I have added the condition @Anant, im still getting the same error

Comment: @SachinS  a correct answer given to you. seems correct to me. check once

Comment: The answer from @haresh seems working

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`array_values()` function accept only `array` type variable
Below line

```
 $updated_f[$f_key] = array_values($assoc_array);   //Warning here
```

Replace line with

```
$updated_f[$f_key] = is_array($assoc_array)? array_values($assoc_array): array();
```